# reverse engineer hex values to time date format

Tags: datetime, timestamp, hex, reverse-engineering

I logged the Bluetooth transmission between two devices and I want to reverse engineer the protocol. I figured everything out but not the date time format.
I have the following known pairs of hex values and dates:

```
00:fe:a6:11:f5:0d:c7:19:00:ff:01:09:00:00:00:00  --> 03.06.2017 - 07:44:06
00:fe:68:40:f4:0d:da:15:00:ff:01:09:00:00:00:00  --> 02.06.2017 - 16:51:20
00:fe:33:3d:f4:0d:c6:14:00:ff:01:09:00:00:00:00  --> 02.06.2017 - 16:37:39
00:fe:83:1d:f4:0d:ba:15:00:ff:01:09:00:00:00:00  --> 02.06.2017 - 14:22:27
00:fe:c2:19:f4:0d:7d:16:00:ff:01:09:00:00:00:00  --> 02.06.2017 - 14:06:26
00:fe:f5:15:f4:0d:b2:16:00:ff:01:09:00:00:00:00  --> 02.06.2017 - 13:50:13
00:fe:67:14:f4:0d:e4:16:00:ff:01:09:00:00:00:00  --> 02.06.2017 - 13:43:35
00:fe:80:0f:f4:0d:6a:17:00:ff:01:09:00:00:00:00  --> 02.06.2017 - 13:22:40
```

How can I convert it from hex values to the date/time format? I already tried if they transmit the date/time in a unix time stamp format but it seems they are using something differently.

Does somebody see a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx for your answer.

I discovered how the date and time is decoded.
Grp 3 and Grp 2 is in little endian the unix time but starting strangely from year 2010 and not from 1970.

So I have to add 40 years to get the correct year.

For example:

```
00:fe:a6:11:f5:0d:c7:19:00:ff:01:09:00:00:00:00  --> 03.06.2017 - 07:44:06
```

unix time decoded:

```
0d:f5:11:a6 --> 234164646 -> unix time stamp 1977-06-03T05:44:06+00:00 in ISO 8601
```

adding 40 years to this unix time stamp I get the correct date and time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd need to have a lot more data to be able to fully understand what's going on, but here's what I could gather from the limited data available:

```
|Grp 1 |Grp 2 |Grp 3 |Grp 4 | Grp 5     | Padding?   |
|------|------|------|------|-----------|------------|
|00 fe |a6 11 |f5 0d |c7 19 |00 ff 01 09|00 00 00 00 | : 03.06.2017 - 07:44:06
|00 fe |68 40 |f4 0d |da 15 |00 ff 01 09|00 00 00 00 | : 02.06.2017 - 16:51:20
|00 fe |33 3d |f4 0d |c6 14 |00 ff 01 09|00 00 00 00 | : 02.06.2017 - 16:37:39
|00 fe |83 1d |f4 0d |ba 15 |00 ff 01 09|00 00 00 00 | : 02.06.2017 - 14:22:27
|00 fe |c2 19 |f4 0d |7d 16 |00 ff 01 09|00 00 00 00 | : 02.06.2017 - 14:06:26
|00 fe |f5 15 |f4 0d |b2 16 |00 ff 01 09|00 00 00 00 | : 02.06.2017 - 13:50:13
|00 fe |67 14 |f4 0d |e4 16 |00 ff 01 09|00 00 00 00 | : 02.06.2017 - 13:43:35
|00 fe |80 0f |f4 0d |6a 17 |00 ff 01 09|00 00 00 00 | : 02.06.2017 - 13:22:40
```

- Group 1: Year?
- Group 2: Not sure. Might be tied into how the time is calculated.
- Group 3: I'm fairly confident this is the day and month. It's packed pretty tightly, if my guess is correct.
- Group 4: I have a hunch this is the hour/minutes/seconds. At the very least, this and Group 2 are linked together in some way.
- Group 5: Unlikely related to timestamps.
- Padding: I'm assuming this is just empty space that is never used.

The only way to truly be able to reverse the protocol would be to have lots of varying information. Dates with varying years/months/days and timestamps with similar hours but different minutes/seconds, etc.

Apologies if this doesn't help you much, either way good luck!